# R Shiny: non-equivalency between Boolean output values and output of checkboxInput

Tags: r, shiny, types, boolean

I'm in the process of building a Shiny app that includes a `conditionalPanel()`, triggered by a Boolean expression.

In my final app, the hope is to have a password creation panel that will display for users who have not yet set a password. Password lookup is based on a `selectInput()` widget that allows the user to select their username and an external CSV that maps usernames to passwords (password hash codes).

To trigger the `conditionalPanel()`, the username selection must not equal the default ("---") and the value of an output variable called `pw_is_set` must be equal to `FALSE`. (The latter should occur when the password lookup for the selected user returns a value of `NA`)

Oddly, I'm running into an issue where the behavior of the `conditionalPanel()` depends on how I set the value of `pw_is_set`. When I use a `checkboxInput()`, the logic works perfectly. But when I try to write a custom expression that returns a (base R) Boolean, the `conditionalPanel()` never triggers. In both cases, I'm assigning a value to `output$pw_is_set` with `renderText()`.

I'm hoping someone can help me understand the difference because a `checkboxInput()` is not viable for my final app.

The following code should fully reproduce my issue. The default version uses `checkboxInput()` and produces the exact behavior I'm looking for.

The version that *doesn't* work can be toggled by commenting-out lines 22 and 65 and uncommenting lines 62-64.

```
library(shiny)
library(cli)

##### Facsimile of the external 'user_roster' CSV #####
user_roster <- data.frame(name=c("User A", "User B", "User C"),
                          password_hash=rep(NA, 3),
                          stringsAsFactors=F)

user_list <- user_roster$name


##### UI #####
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("selected_user", h3("Name"),
                  choices=c("---", get("user_list", envir=.GlobalEnv))),
      
      ## Temp Controls & Data Validation
      br(),
      h4("Temporary Controls & Data Validation"),
      #checkboxInput("pw_is_set", "Password is set", FALSE),
      p("Value returned by ", em("Password is Set"), ": ", textOutput("pw_is_set", inline=T)),
      br(),
      p("Name of selected user: ", textOutput("user_name", inline=T)),
      p("Password hash for selected user: ", textOutput("user_pw_hash", inline=T)),
      br(),
      
      ## Password creation panel
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.selected_user!='---' && output.pw_is_set==false",
        p(strong("It looks like this is your first time here. Please create a password for your account.")),
        p("Please do not use your [work] password or any other sensitive identifiers. This password is intended to maintain user privacy, but is not truly secure", style="color:red"),
        passwordInput("new_pw_1", "Password"),
        passwordInput("new_pw_2", "Re-type password")
      )
    ),
    
    ## Main panel    
    mainPanel("MAIN PANEL")
  )
)


##### Server #####
server <- function(input, output, session){
  # Create an output object called `user_name` based on user-provided input
  output$user_name <- renderText({
    user_name <- input$selected_user
    return(user_name)
  })
  
  # Create an output object called `user_pw_hash` based on user-provided input
  output$user_pw_hash <- renderText({
    user_roster <- get("user_roster", envir=.GlobalEnv)
    user_pw_hash <- user_roster$password_hash[which(user_roster$name==input$selected_user)]
    return(user_pw_hash)
  })
  
  # Create an output object called `pw_is_set` based on user-provided input
  output$pw_is_set <- renderText({
    user_roster <- get("user_roster", envir=.GlobalEnv)
    user_pw_hash <- user_roster$password_hash[which(user_roster$name==input$selected_user)]
    pw_is_set <- !is.na(user_pw_hash)
    #pw_is_set <- input$pw_is_set
    return(pw_is_set)
  })
}

##### App Launcher #####
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `renderText` returns a character string not a boolean, i.e. in you conditional table you have to use `output.pw_is_set === 'FALSE'` to check whether `pw_is_set` is equal to the string `"FALSE"`:

[image]